# Twitter alerts for keyword volume per hour

Tags: monitoring, twitter, real-time, alarm

My company has a twitter account that normally gets 10-20 mentions per day.  If I start getting 30+ mentions in a day, I know that something in my application is broken.

How can I set up a monitoring service that will only trigger if the number of messages / mentions / keyword sets exceeds X times per Y timespan?

Comment: Your question lacks some important details.  First of all, how are you monitoring your Twitter account?

Comment: This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center. To be more specific, SuperUser is not about websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress.

Comment: Use Yo! https://github.com/YoApp/retweets-yo/blob/master/retweet.py

Comment: I'm happy to use any service that would let me do this.

As to SU not being the correct StackExchange site for this question - what is the correct site?  I'm happy to move it.